# ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found

Tags: ffmpeg

I am installing ffmpeg utility, but I am facing `libmp3lame >= 3.98.3` not found not found error. I am able to find `lame-3.99.5-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm` and `lame-libs-3.98.4-1.el6.nux.x86_64.rpm` but installing these are not solving the problem. I am not able to find libmp3lame rpm to install.

Can anyone help me here?

> [root@sdp-dev-03:/opt/ffmpeg] # ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvpx --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --disable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-nonfree --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads
>
> ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
`ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org` mailing list or IRC `#ffmpeg` on `irc.freenode.net`.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.

Comment: Are you following a guide/tutorial? If yes, please provide the link. It appears to be using some text from the FFmpeg Wiki, but there are some differences and useless stuff added.

Comment: Here is the link   http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/FFMpeg+Installation+on+CentOS+and+RedHat

Answer (score 15):

What worked for me was building lame from source. Download lame from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/files/lame/3.99/, then extract and install:

```
tar -zxvf lame-3.99.5.tar.gz 
cd lame-3.99.5
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Check to see where libmp3lame.a is:

> locate libmp3lame.a

Its probably in /usr/local/lib.

Now when you go to configure ffmpeg, try adding that path to the end of your ./configure string. For me it made the difference. e.g.:

```
--extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: In case you didn't scroll down and see Wayne's answer, I also had to set the `--extra-cflags` flag to set the include directory when I was compiling LAME and FFMPEG to my home directory. This was on a Ubuntu 16.04 system with LAME 3.100 and FFMPEG 3.4.1.

Comment: If you're a macports user, use `/opt/local/...` in place of `/usr/local/...` throughout your configure string.

Answer (score 10):

For `configure` troubleshooting see the `ffbuild/config.log` in the `ffmpeg` source directory.

In my case it had missing references to `libmath` functions, even if `-lm` was set in `host_extralibs`.

For a quick-fix add `-lm` to the `configure` script:

```
enabled libmp3lame        && require "libmp3lame >= 3.98.3" lame/lame.h lame_set_VBR_quality -lmp3lame -lm
```

Comment: Hi again, @aergistal. Did you get some workaround? I've just got the same problem when building functions from _libmp3lame_ 3.100, which released a few days ago. I'm going to report this to `ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You made me happy. :)

Comment: Thanks @K._ this fixed it for me. I was installing ffmpeg on an AWS EC2 instance:

`sed -i -e 's/\(3.98.3..lame.lame.h.lame.set.VBR.quality..lmp3lame\)/\1 -lm/' ./configure`

Comment: Everyone else wondering, you have to add the -lm option to the ffmpeg configure script and not libmp3lame. This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is now fixed in the git version

Comment: Could it be that this is how the mp3 library version eval is failing: 3.100 < 3.98.3?

Answer (score 6):

I just experienced this problem.  I had `lame v3.99.5` installed, but `ffmpeg` configure was giving `ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3` not found.

In addition to `--extra-ldflags`, I had to specify `--extra-cflags`.  So, the configure line was:

```
./configure [...] --enable-libmp3lame [...] --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include
```

Comment: This worked for me thank you. The only catch is that if lame is installed on macos with brew, than the paths might be different. In my case they're `--extra-cflags="-I/opt/homebrew/include" --extra-ldflags="-L/opt/homebrew/lib"`

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install yasm libmp3lame-dev
```

Then configure ffmpeg to build from source with libmp3lame:

```
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-shared
```

Comment: FFmpeg currently supports lame ≥ 3.98.3, so the libmp3lame-dev package should work on all supported Debian and Ubuntu versions as well since they all provide at least 3.99.5. nasm is now preferred over yasm because yasm development seems to have stagnated.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard For whatever reason, the other solutions here were not working, but the above did. You say ffmpeg will find and use nasm, if yasm is not installed?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution for ffmpeg/3.1.3 (based on https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/44489) was to add:

```
--host-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib
```

to the configure string.

Answer (score 0):

this is my way:

install X11,and goto ffmpeg path,and code this in the Terminal:

```
    pkg-config usr/local/lib
    pkg-config usr/lib
    pkg-config usr/X11/lib
```

then code `./configure xxxx.`

Comment: thanks a lot, that time i don't know how to format it，it‘s very embarrassment

Comment: I don't see what x11 has to do with libmp3lame.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard thanks, maybe just need 'pkg-config ' , i think.