# How to include library header when building with Emscripten?

Tags: compilation, ubuntu-18.04, emscripten, lame, emcc

I am trying to build [codecbox.js](https://github.com/duanyao/codecbox.js) on Ubuntu 18.04, which involves building FFmpeg with emcc. I have been stuck with [the misleading `libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found` error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937403/error-libmp3lame-3-98-3-not-found/46208497#46208497). In my case, there is no problem with libmp3lame installation. After further investigation into FFmpeg's `configure` script, I found out that the following test file failed to compile with emcc:

```
#include <lame/lame.h>
#include <stdint.h>

long check_lame_set_VBR_quality(void) { return (long) lame_set_VBR_quality; }
int main(void) {
    int ret = 0;
    ret |= ((intptr_t)check_lame_set_VBR_quality) & 0xFFFF;
    return ret;
}
```

I get `fatal error: 'lame/lame.h' file not found`.

I found the header in `/usr/include/lame` so I tried compiling with `emcc -I/usr/include`. This removed the error but introduced plenty of other errors.

Then I read ([for example here](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#why-does-compiling-code-that-works-on-another-machine-gives-me-errors)) that I should not use local system headers, which happens when I add option `-I/usr/include`.

So what is the proper way to ensure emcc finds my library header whilst using Emscripten bundled system headers provided within the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/include/lame` sounds like you are building it with the system installation.
You are not supposed to build an emscriten module with any system-wide packages though. Imagine you are distributing the emscripten-compiled package to the web, not to someone else's desktop. You probably want to get the source of ffmpeg and other related libraries manually.

Comment: OK, I see. In fact, library lame is included in codecbox.js so I just have to point to it, not to the system's one.